# Is there a hook to change the WordPress "reset password form"?

Tags: php, wordpress

I was able to change the "lost password form" to:

```
// Change html
function html_lostpassword_form(){
    $html = ''; // <input> etc.
}

// Read file
function my_echo_files(){
    $files = '
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/css/lostpassword.css" />
        <script src="' . get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/lostpassword.js"></script>
    ';
    echo $files;
}

// Change the lost password form
function my_password_form() {
    // Change html
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    $content = html_lostpassword_form();
    ob_get_clean();
    echo $content;
    // Read file
    my_echo_files();    
}
add_action( 'lostpassword_form', 'my_password_form' );
```

When I want to change the "lost password form" `lostpassword_form` is useful,

Then What should I do to in the case of "reset password form"?

It was not possible with `resetpassword_form` or `rp_form`.

Now, "lost password form" is the page displayed in "example.com/wp-login?action=lostpassword",
and "reset password form" is the page displayed in "example.com/wp-login?action=rp".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean `resetpass_form` action hook. Here is [the description](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/resetpass_form/).

When searching for hooks, you can use the [code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-login.php/?post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook). Similar hooks are usually located in the same file, so you can find them easily. E.g. search for "lostpassword_form", then follow it's source file  link (`wp-login.php` in this case). And then use a filter in the top of the page to show all action hooks in this file. Then you can open hook page and even check the "view on track" link to see how it is used in code directly.

Note that WP has a huge legacy. This means that names of some functions and hooks are not very intuitive sometimes and may slightly differ from that you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
May I ask you something? 
Why can I overwrite "$content" in case "lostpassword_form" and "register_form" but do not in case "resetpass_form" ?

Comment: You should ask WP core developers instead :) Hooks are implemented by different people in different versions. So, as I've already said, WP is not always intuitive due to its nature and long history. Maybe one day core team will add `$content` support to this hook, too. And if you use ClassicPress, you can ask for this feature via petitions system. It seems to be a rather easy one to implement.

Comment: Noted.Thank you very much for your quick reply.

Comment: Excuse me for taking more of your time. But I still have a question regarding hook and would appreciate it if you could help. "resetpass_form" is the hook for "example.com/wp-login?action=rp", but do you know the hook for "example.com/wp-login?loggedout=true"?

Comment: `logout_redirect` — https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/logout_redirect/

Comment: Thank you for the response.You are ingenious!